# How to validate FromDate and Todate in SSRS reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to validate From date is cannot greater than To date in SSRS Reports.

Comment: Can you show the data / query that you're comparing against? You can really only set a calendar parameter to "any date", but you could bind the default values against your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing a list of dates the user can select from a report Dataset, there is no way to do this in SSRS.  If having a `FromDate` after your `ToDate` will somehow cause issues in your datasets (surely they would just return blank?) you will need to add your validation there.

Comment: can you please provide any information on how to do validation there?

Comment: Depends on your queries and how you are getting the data into your datasets.  One example would be to have `where @FromDate <= @ToDate` in your query, so a blank dataset is returned.